# return type of std::bind implicitly convertible to two different explicit constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

Given two **`explicit`** constructor overloads (based on different `std::function<...>` types), the return value of `std::bind` is able to select **either** (thereby making the call ambiguous)

```
call of overloaded ‘Bar(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Foo::*)(int), 
    Foo*, int>::type)’ is ambiguous
```

If I comment out either, then the code compiles!

I would have thought making the constructors `explicit` would have either selected the correct overload, or prevented both from being selected?

Of course **explicitly** creating a `std::function` at the point I bind works:

```
    Bar b(std::function<void(int)>(std::bind((&Foo::process), &f, 1)));
```

However, I'm puzzled as to why type deduction doesn't work?

- If the return value from `std::bind` matches neither of the two constructor signatures, the fact they are `explicit` should prevent both from being selected.
- If the return value from `std::bind` matches one of the two constructor signatures, the fact they are `explicit` should cause the correct one to be selected.

What is actually happening here?

**Full working code below:**

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    void process(int) { }
};

struct Bar
{
    // comment out either of these to compile
    explicit Bar(std::function<void(int)>) {} 
    explicit Bar(std::function<void(short)>) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b(std::bind(&Foo::process, &f, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the constructor `explicit` has nothing to do with the arguments having to match exactly! The affect of making a constructor explicit means that it won't be used to implicitly convert an object of a different type the type `Bar` using this constructor. However, if you try to initialize a `Bar` object using direct initialization (i.e., `Bar(x)`), both constructors will be considered.

The result of `std::bind()` is certainly not a `std::function<Signature>`, i.e., it doesn't match either of your constructors exactly. Since there is a non-`explicit` constructor for `std::function<Signature>` which works for function objects, both signatures do match: the produced bind expression doesn't require any parameter but it can take arguments, i.e., any argument type also cannot be used to distinguish which of the two constructors of `Bar` should match. Even if the bind expression would require one argument, I don't think it would be used to prefer one constructor over another.